# How to properly change the Joomla Protostar Template and use the right path for the css and images files?

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

for my assignment next week we have to know following:

- We get a template (not a Joomla template, but a website template with existing html and css + images). This template we have to "import" into Joomla and then add the menus, articles, etc. in Joomla for it
- We have to just delete the protostar template files and paste in the template files, then rename the index.html to index.php

When I do this it works however with no css (because of the paths to css and images).
For example the standard path from my template is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
```

This, however, won't work.
I tried a few things and that worked:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/protostar/css/animate.css">
```

But I don't know why templates/protostar is the root? I thought the root is the folder in which the index.php is located?

If I do the same with the images

```
<div class="fh5co-portfolio-figure animate-box" style="background-image: url(images/work_1.jpg);"></div>
```

to `<div class="fh5co-portfolio-figure animate-box" style="background-image: url(templates/protostar/images/work_1.jpg);"></div>`

this won't work. So the pictures still won't show on the page.

So could anyone explain to me that behavior and how to do this right?

Comment: Uh, what? If you are importing another template you don't need to overwrite the protostar one, you can just enable your new template. Also, Joomla has a lot of documentation and guides on how to use templates / writing your own templates, try googling for it. (As for the paths, [Joomla has plenty of ways to set absolute / relative path according to your needs](https://docs.joomla.org/Constants),).

Comment: Sorry I think I was not clear enough. I don't meant a whole Joomla template. I meant a website template with html, css and images.

Comment: That is what I'm talking about, Joomla is a CMS which allows you to install "website templates", there's still no need to modify the protostar one when you install a new one.

Comment: i think you are messing between file paths and html resources path. When you load a file from PHP, you are right, the relative path depends from where your index.php is located. But html resources are relative to the page URL, if there is url rewriting, these 2 paths can be different (and they are in your case)

Comment: Our teacher said that we have to modify the protostar. I tried your suggestion but don't get it to work. When I choose the zip file I get an error: 
Error

Archive does not exist
Unable to find install package

Also when I unzip it first and then navigate into it I can't chose anything because I think it expects a zip file.
@Kaddath ok thanks that makes it a bit clearer. But why won't the images work?

Comment: @DominikHuber things can get complicated with URL rewriting, let's say for example that your page loads with an article alias `site.com/my-article/`. In this case, the html document thinks he is really in the `my-article` folder even if it doesn't exist and URL is rewritten to something like `index.php?var=value`. It means most of the time, it will be safer to start your resources URL from root, like `/templates/protostar/css/animate.css` (with a leading slash)

Comment: @Kaddath with the leading slash it won't work. Without it it works. But not for the images. No matter how I try out the link it won't display the pictures. The images are in the folder "images" in the protostar folder. So the path I tried was: ```url(/templates/protostar/images/work_1.jpg)``` Also without the leading slash it won't work. The css files work (without the leading slash). This background url is an inline style element in the same index.php document btw.

Comment: @DominikHuber using just a single slash will work only if your site is in the root or your domain, if in a subfolder, you have to specify it. Fortunately, you don't have to worry about that in joomla, because you won't load your css in html, but with handy Joomla PHP functions. You will do the same for image paths, retreiving the good path from Joomla functions. example for a css file: `JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'my-file-in-template-css-folder.css', array('version' => '1.0', 'relative' => true));`

Comment: We haven't ever learned about that JHtml function. Is this the only way to get the images to work? Sorry I'm so confused right now. I have the website running but without the images. I still think that the problem is something with the path of the images. Do I have to use this JHtml:: tag?

Comment: sorry, i show you advanced ways that can confuse you, my example was another way to do a css file import, a more comprehensible is `$document = JFactory::getDocument(); $document->addStyleSheet($url);`. For the images it is different, you should build the path with something like this in PHP: `echo '<img src="' . $this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/images/example.jpg' . ' alt="" />';`, but $this will be different depending on the type of file you are in

Comment: First of all start by copying protostar to a new folder. Edit that.  Just follow exactly what protostar does for all of this, why are you reinventing the wheel?  Put your images where the protostar images are in the copied verstion.